# Iterating through an object and rendering data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an exercise app. How would I go about iterating through this objects property "suoritusStats" in a way that I can render the "suoritusStats" in a way such as "toistot - toistot - toistot", so in this case "painot" property would be rendered like "0-0-10", and toistot "10-10-10" in order.

At the moment from the last map function, I get for example "10" rendered once, but as stated above, I need to render them in a such fashion described. So "toistot" would be
"toistot: 10-10-10", not "toistot: 10".

Here is my data structure (it's an array of objects) but I've just cut down so that it won't be too long.

```
Array [
  Object {
    "pvm": "3. heinäkuuta 2021",
    "timestamp": 1625325753617,
    "treeni": "Rintatreeni",
    "treeniData": Object {
      "Punnerrukset": Object {
        "id": 0,
        "nimi": "Punnerrukset",
        "sarjat": "3",
        "suoritusStats": Array [
          Object {
            "painot": "0",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
          Object {
            "painot": "0",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
          Object {
            "painot": "10",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]
```

Here is my return statement:

```
 {
   treenit.map((item, index) => (
    
        
    <List.Accordion 
    key={index}
    title={<Text small left>{item.pvm} - {item.treeni}</Text>}
    left={props => <List.Icon {...props} icon="calendar" color={themeColor} />}
    >
 {
       Object.values(item.treeniData).map(treeni => {
        let descSarjat = `Sarjat: ${treeni.sarjat}`;
           let descToistot;
           let descPainot;

            Object.values(treeni.suoritusStats).map((item) => {
                descToistot = `Toistot: ${item.toistot}`;
                descPainot = `Painot: ${item.painot}`;
            
            })

           return(
            <List.Item 
            descriptionNumberOfLines={3}
            descriptionStyle={{fontFamily: 'MontserratRegular', color: themeColor}}
            titleStyle={{fontFamily: 'MontserratSemiBold', color: themeColor}}
            key={treeni.nimi} title={treeni.nimi} 
            description={`${descSarjat}\n${descToistot}\n${descPainot}`} 
            />
           ) 
           
       })
   }
 
   </List.Accordion>
       
 ))
 }
```

Thank you in advance for taking your time! Appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
let descToistot =`Toistot: `;
let descPainot= `Painot: `;

treeni.suoritusStats.map((item, i) => {
   descToistot += `${i===0?"":"-"}${item.toistot}`;
   descPainot += `${i===0?"":"-"}${item.painot}`;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, this is pure JS. Nothing with React.

```js
const arr= [
  {
    "pvm": "3. heinäkuuta 2021",
    "timestamp": 1625325753617,
    "treeni": "Rintatreeni",
    "treeniData":  {
      "Punnerrukset":  {
        "id": 0,
        "nimi": "Punnerrukset",
        "sarjat": "3",
        "suoritusStats":  [
           {
            "painot": "0",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
           {
            "painot": "0",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
           {
            "painot": "10",
            "toistot": "10",
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]

const datas = arr[0].treeniData.Punnerrukset.suoritusStats;
const toistotArr = [];

datas.map(data => toistotArr.push(data.toistot));
const dashedResult = toistotArr.join('-');
console.log(dashedResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for the same:

```js
Array.map(({ treeniData = {} }) => {
      const { Punnerrukset = {} } = treeniData;
      const obj = {};
      Object.keys(Punnerrukset).forEach((punnKey) => {
        const punnerValue = Punnerrukset[punnKey];
        if (Array.isArray(punnerValue)) {
          punnerValue.forEach((suorKeys) => {
            Object.keys(suorKeys).forEach((val) => {
              if (obj[val]) {
                obj[val] += "-" + suorKeys[val];
              } else {
                obj[val] = val + ":";
                obj[val] += suorKeys[val];
              }
            });
          });
        } else if (punnKey === "sarjat") {
          obj[punnKey] = punnKey + ":" + punnerValue;
        } else {
          obj[punnKey] = punnerValue;
        }
      });
      const { painot = "", sarjat = "", toistot = "" } = obj;
      return (
        <div>
          {`${sarjat}\n ${painot}\n ${toistot}\n`}
        </div>
      );
    });
```